# Using multiple FCGI binaries on one lighttpd instance - possible?

Tags: lighttpd, fastcgi

It seems to me that it will be more maintainable to keep separate functions of my site in  separate FCGI binaries.  What I want is for requests like these:

```
http://mysite.com/funcA.fcgi
http://mysite.com/funcB.fcgi?action=go
```

To be redirected to the appropriate files:

```
/var/fcgi/funcA.fcgi
/var/fcgi/funcB.fcgi
```

So, in my lighttpd.conf file, I would need something like this:

```
fastcgi.server =
( ".fcgi" =>
  (( "bin-path" => "/var/fcgi",
     "socket" => "tmp/fcgi.sock",
     "check-local" => "disable"
  ))
)
```

Or maybe it would have to be more like this:

```
fastcgi.server = 
( "funcA.fcgi" =>
  (( "bin-path" => "/var/fcgi/funcA.fcgi",
     "socket" => "tmp/fcgi.sock",
     "check-local" => "disable"
  ))
),
( "funcB.fcgi" =>
  (( "bin-path" => "/var/fcgi/funcB.fcgi",
     "socket" => "tmp/fcgi.sock",
     "check-local" => "disable"
  ))
)
```

Or am I maybe missing something else altogether?  I can only get lighttpd to start when there is a single binary being pointed to.

EDIT: To make sure I'm being clear: what I need is for a request like `mysite.com/x.fcgi` to invoke `/var/fcgi/x.fcgi`, and likewise a request to `mysite.com/y.fcgi` to invoke `/var/fcgi/y.fcgi`.  It seems to be like this should be pretty straightforward, but I can't get a lighttpd configuration that makes this happen.

Also, I'm not using anything interpreted.  These are compiled C++ binaries using the `fcgi_stdio.h` header.

Would I perhaps need to use mod_rewrite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it looks to me like what I want to do is impossible, or at least not provided for under FCGI.  When you invoke `www.mydomain.com/thing1.fcgi`, you're not *starting* `thing1.fcgi`; that has already been done.  What you're doing is sending a request to the infinitely-running FCGI process that you write, which almost certainly has a infinite loop right at the heart of it, waiting for requests.  This is just the nature of FCGI, and a major distinction from the earlier CGI.

Not a hard question to answer, once you understand how FCGI works.  I guess I was just wishing.

Answer (score -1):

https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/docs_modfastcgi
It can be done, several binaries in a lighttpd config.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Your answer suggests a workable solution to the question is available via another website. The Stack Exchange family of Q&A websites [generally frowns on this type of answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). Please read [How do I write a good answer?](http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-answer) and consider revising your answer to include the steps required to resolve the issue. And don't forget to take the [site tour](http://serverfault.com/tour).

Comment: I was working on a lighttpd configuration with two binaries, here you have:

Comment: $HTTP["host"] == "localhost" {
   fastcgi.server = (
      "/web" => ((
         "bin-path" => "/home/eduardo/bin/echofcgi fastcgi",
         "max-procs" => 3,
         "check-local" => "disable",
         "fix-root-scriptname" => "enable",
         "port" => 1025
      )),
      "/restservices" => ((
         "bin-path" => "/home/eduardo/bin/echofcgi2 fastcgi",
         "max-procs" => 3,
         "check-local" => "disable",
         "fix-root-scriptname" => "enable",
         "port" => 1027
      ))
   )
}

Comment: As I stated above, please edit your answer.